# May i know why this exception is occurring?

Tags: android, android-launcher

while launching my app I am getting following exception:

I am adding my code at below please check once

```
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.thenewboston.travis/com.thenewboston.travis.Splash}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at com.thenewboston.travis.Splash.onCreate(Splash.java:16)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  ... 11 more
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  ... 23 more
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3328)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:431)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:176)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:172)
05-16 10:44:16.653: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  ... 26 more
```

I am adding my code at below please check once
I don't know why inflate exception is occurring 
I am new to Android please help me

**Splash.java**

```
package com.thenewboston.travis;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class Splash extends Activity{
MediaPlayer mySong;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        mySong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.honey);

        SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        boolean musicChk = getPrefs.getBoolean("checkbox", true);
        if(musicChk == true)

            mySong.start();

        Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(1000);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();                    
                }finally{
                    System.out.println("Coming HERE...............");
                    Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent ("com.thenewboston.travis.MENU");
                    startActivity(openStartingPoint); 

                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        mySong.release();
        finish();
    }


}
```

Splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/honey">


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it means there is a problem in your code

Comment: Somthing wrong with xml . Post Splash and the xml it inflates

Comment: That java.lang.OutOfMemoryError looks interesting. Perhaps the Drawable for the splash image you're trying to inflate is way too big?

Comment: This always happens with splash screens.  It's God's way of telling you that they are evil. http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/

Answer (score 0):

The name says it all `OutOfMemoryError` means you are trying to allocate more than you should.

`com.thenewboston.travis.Splash` means you are doing that in your splash activty.

Conclusion is you are trying to set a very big image as a background. I'd suggest minimizing the size by using 1 or 2 `9-patches`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2

its nothing but something wrong in your xml file.

1. Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

its means some variable have null values which you try to get.

1. Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

its occurs when you use to get too big image or big size image. mostly it occurs in galaxy s3 mobile whenever you take picture using camera intent.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I am getting this exception due to using wrong size emulator.After i upgrade my emulator configuration the exception is not occurring